# Equation of circle circumscribing a triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Th equation of a circle circumscribing a triangle whose sides in order are represented by the lines ${L_1} = 0$, ${L_2} = 0$, ${L_3} = 0$, is given by ${L_1}{L_2} + \lambda {L_2}{L_3} +\mu {L_3}{L_1}= 0$ provided the coefficients of ${x^2}$ and ${y^2}$ are equal and the coefficient of $xy = 0$. My question is why the equation cannot be just of form ${L_1}{L_2} + \lambda {L_2}{L_3}=0$ leaving the $\mu {L_3}{L_1}$ term because leaving that we still have in all cases of two of the $L_1 ,L_2, L_3$ to be zero both terms would go zero and satisfy the equation . Why the third term is needed ?

Comment: "the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are equal and the coefficient of $xy=0$" Two restrictions requires two degrees of freedom?

Comment: But in case of quadrilateral the equation boils to L1L3 + lamda L2L4 = 0 , even there are two restrictons still we use that @eyeballfrog

Comment: Choose $L_1=x=0$, $L_2=y=0$, $L_3=x+y-1=0$. In your expression you don't have an $x^2$ term.

Comment: Cant the same be said for quadrilateral too?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer - You can see the problem in Andrei's example is real. Obviously this doesn't work for triangles. That answers your question as to why the third term is needed for triangles. "But it works for quadrilaterals" is immaterial to the question for triangles. If you want to know what is going on with quadrilaterals, try to construct a similar counter-example for them. Then you will either see why it cannot be done for quadrilaterals, or else see that your claim about quadrilaterals is false.